# How can I display the full content rich text in read mode via xp:inputTextarea?

Tags: java, xpages, richtext

On an xpage I want to display the full content of a rich text field with help of the xp:inputTextarea control. How can I do this?

The content of the rich text is nothing more than text. There is no rich text content in the fields, so no attachments or formatted (html) text.

I have been able to bind the content of the rich text field to a String field in my java object but when I display it on my xpage via an input text area it gets formatted with so many 
 elements that does not represent the content of the rich text field.

Should I apply a convertor to the input textarea control and how should this look like? or can I use somehow the computed text control?

Comment: Since it's read only anyway, why not just use the xp:inputRichText control?

Comment: have you tried to set escape="false" ?

Comment: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSVRGU_9.0.1/basic/H_ABSTRACT.html

Comment: have you tried just to use the xp:text  ?

Comment: I have tested the xp:inputRichText  but then the new lines are being ignored.

Comment: I tried something with a custom converter on a rich text input control but then I got the data displayed on too many rows: <xp:this.converter>
      <xp:customConverter>
       <xp:this.getAsString><![CDATA[#{javascript:@ReplaceSubstring(value, "\n", "<br />")}]]></xp:this.getAsString>
       <xp:this.getAsObject><![CDATA[#{javascript:@ReplaceSubstring(value, "\n", "<br />")}]]></xp:this.getAsObject>
      </xp:customConverter>
     </xp:this.converter>

Answer (score 0):

Did you try just changing the display type to html? That is on the first tab.

Comment: the rich text does not contain any HTML. so when I set the computed text control to HTML I just get all the text as one long string. However when I add a custom converter and replace the breakline (\n) with a blank row but then I get so many line breaks. I must do something wrong: <xp:this.converter>
    <xp:customConverter
     getAsObject="#{javascript:value.getContentAsText()}">

     <xp:this.getAsString><![CDATA[#{javascript:@ReplaceSubstring(value, "\n", "<br/>")}]]></xp:this.getAsString>

    </xp:customConverter>
     </xp:this.converter>